# How to delete a certain Object from an Array

Tags: jquery

I have an Array as shown below

```
var test = 
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "incentives": "23.45",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Larsen",
    "incentives": "34.78",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "incentives": "26.78",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

I want to remove a certain Object

I have tried as shown below

```
var idtoberemoved = 2

test = test.filter((obj) => typeof obj.id = '2');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/65584/

Comment: it should be `test.filter((obj) => obj.id === '2');`

Comment: once i execute this line , the array length is becoming 1 , where as i removed only one element so it must be 2

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index of the element in the array, and use splice to remove it.

```js
var test = [{
    "name": "Mike",
    "incentives": "23.45",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Larsen",
    "incentives": "34.78",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "incentives": "26.78",
    "id": "3"
  }
];

//Use splice to remove the element
test.splice(
  //find the index of the element to be removed
  test.indexOf(test.find(function(element){ return element.id === "2"; }))
  //remove 1 element from the index found
  , 1
);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof obj.id` will give you `"string"`, and you want to filter out the objects whose `id` property is not equalt to `"2"`. So, it should be

```
test.filter(obj => obj.id !== '2');
```

In JS, `=` is for assignment, not for equality test. We use `==`, `===`, `!==`, `!=` for equality tests. There are difference between `==` and `===`, but that is a whole subject.

Comment: The length is 1 , but it must be 2 know ,because i removed only 1 object from the array

Comment: @Pawan I am not getting you.

Comment: make it `test.filter(obj => obj.id !== '2');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var test = [
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "incentives": "23.45",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Larsen",
            "incentives": "34.78",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "incentives": "26.78",
            "id": "3"
        }
    ];
    
    var filtered = test.filter(function(object) {
    
        return object.id != 2;
    });
    
    console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more than one id being removed, here is one more way to accomplish using reduce. This is not very different from the other approaches and answers, but a different way to accomplish the ask.

```js
var test = [{
    "name": "Mike",
    "incentives": "23.45",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Larsen",
    "incentives": "34.78",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "incentives": "26.78",
    "id": "3"
  }
];

function removeItem(idList) {

  var result = test.reduce(function(output, currentObject) {
    if (!idList.includes(currentObject.id)) {
      output.push(currentObject);
    }
    return output;
  }, []);
  return result;
}


console.log(removeItem(["2", '3']))
```